# React Components - No Inheritance, how can pass ref or use HOC for my BaseComponent

Tags: reactjs, components, ref, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm building a Web components library where I have a series of components which ideally inherit / takes advantage of BaseComponent. After some reading, inheritance isn't recommended in React and instead I could use forwardRef? or probably higher-order components? The only thing, I'm not very familiar with this concept and couldn't find good examples, tutorial specific for my case. Hopefully someone can tell me how to approach this, what's best-practice?

One of technique I have in mind for the BaseComponent is leveraging IntersectionObserver to trigger animations. As you can imagine, I don't want to put this logic in multiple places. For the sick of having a basic example, below I simply have a click event listener on the BaseComponent:

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (     
      <div>
        <div>
          <img className={className} src={src} alt={alt} />     
        </div>   
      </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default Image;
// export default withMagic(Image); ??


class BaseComponent extends React.Component {

  withMagic() {

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    {/* ref should be <img> DOM element */}
    ref.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }
}

export BaseComponent();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HoC probably the better solution

```
// 2. WrappedComponent
export default WrappedComponent => {
    // If u want to deal with class
    class NewComponent extends React.Component {
         //3
         handleClick = () => {
              // Your Events
         }
         render () {
             //4
             return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
         }
    }
    // If u want to deal with functional Component
    const NewComponent = props => {
        const handleClick = () => // your events
        return <WrappedComponent {...props} handleClick={handleClick} />
    }

    return NewComponent
}
```

How to use ?

```
import withClick from 'path/withClick'
const A = props => {
    return (
         //4
         <button onClick={props.handleClick}>Click here</button>
    )
}

// 1. 
export default withClick(A)
```

How this magic work ?

1. U are using `withClick` method by passing `A` component as a params
2. `A` component is named as `WrappedComponent` inside `withClick` function
3. inside the withClick function, u create a new component with your desired handler, logic or even state, then pass them as a props into `WrappedComponent`
4. after that, ur current component will have these handler or logic

If u want to pass params, u can use Higher order Function that returns Higher Order Component like

```
export default (params1, params2, ...paramsn) => WrappedComponent => {
// remain like the same
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaslie, that was definitely helpful! One thing I needed and which was missing is the ref but the following worked:

```return <WrappedComponent ref={(ref) => this.ref = ref} {...props} handleClick={handleClick} />```

Comment: Nice..., May i know why u need ref ? Doesn't u have to use ref, if u want to access child's props, states, or functions ?